# Why does the following code cause unstable deadlock?

Tags: java, synchronized

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsAKe.png)

I want to verify the synchronized keyword!!But the results didn't agree with what I predicted!!I don't understand why deadlocks happen

```java
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private int atomicInteger = 0;

    public void writer() {
        dd();
    }

    public void reader() {
        dd();
    }

    public synchronized void dd() {
        atomicInteger++;
    }

    public void test() {
        lock.lock();
        atomicInteger = 0;
        Thread writer = new Thread(this::writer);
        Thread reader = new Thread(this::reader);
        writer.start();
        reader.start();
        for (; ; ) {
            if (atomicInteger == 2) {
                lock.unlock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"Lock released！");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void volatileTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(this::test);
            thread.setName("thread【" + i + "】");
            thread.start();
        }
        for (; ; ) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What results did you expect, and what happened?

Comment: Your atomicInteger is not volatile, the changes made to it in one thread are not visible in another.

Comment: As an alternative to making `atominInteger` `volatile` you could check it in a `synchronized` block in `test`.

Comment: I used synchronized to make sure the atominIntger will  be updated to main memory when it has been amended! But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Also .. if you make any methods that are called in a synchronized method or block, then those must be a synchronized method (use synchronized keyword).

Comment: As more than a general rule always "return" a value from a method ! That includes objects from methods that must be in place in that part of the sequence. A void method only completes(returns) "sometime" . Liken void to Thread.yeld() being a notation to "being ready" compared to athread.stop() being complicit and actual. synchronize keyword is itself an exclusive lock on the process thread to prevent other sequence parts being able to reach and change variables in the executing code block during the sequence.

Comment: ..as for endless for(;;) loop, is that a "keep alive".  ?   Why the giant recursive mess from a stem cell?  For the methods that call dd() it may be better they return type java.lang.Void with a return statement, but that is only a guess, it's because the atomicinteger  is "global" so cannot be directly assigned in a sequence with a left and right value assignment on one line.

Comment: If you assign "volatile" keyword, the variable"s" must be both global and declared ---in sequence---.  ### they### are to be updated!  Using volatile disallows the update of a later declared variable until the update of any variable before it. Consequently to run a piece of code with volatile keyword variables, it minimal process lines and variables are better committed in their own capsule of a class.(probably preferably a nested subclass).

Comment: You could change reader writer to return the 
counter variable, but the calling methods are void, but if you used the dd() callers on the counter to return, then they will need to be synchronized also (not because of the counter method, because they must both match immediate and locked updating sequence) ,  probably the better solution than using type Void.

Comment: All things being what they are, most of the code is not controlled.inside synchronized blocks or with any process stage completion checking against ordered structured achieved sequence, gives the JVM when and which object it gives priority to, apart from the settings of the Thread objects(runnables, callables) of their priority. Note the reason for thread class is to give runtime process more automated control for cohesive operation of all the parts together, "flexibility" between job achievement and JVM control and it's runtime operation.

Comment: Sooooo,. .....  what's wrong?

Comment: Starting from the origin, that code appears to spawn new Threads in a "tree hierarchy" , if a thread is told to "wait" all the threads spawned by that thread will also be made to wait, if that  or any thread should completed before other threads stages are reached then they may not necessarily be able to complete to be able to call or be called to continue, this deadlocking because they ate all waiting!

Comment: Of main memory, and local memory (note in one tutorial static on java, and the word coherence, particularly with relevence to parallelism)....    1.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile     2.   https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.edureka.co/blog/volatile-keyword-in-java/amp/

Answer (score 1):

For a correct multi-threaded program, it is not enough to add `synchronized` to some accesses to a shared mutable variable. You have to guard *all* accesses to the variable.

Your `dd()` uses `synchronized` for the `atomicInteger++` statement but your `atomicInteger == 2` test does not, so there is no guaranty that this test will ever perceive the updates made by the other threads.

Phrases like “updated to main memory” exhibit a wrong mindset. This is not, how it works. To ensure that a thread perceives an update made by another thread, you must ensure that there is a [*happens-before* order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) between these two actions. This relation is transitive, so you can use a chain of *happens-before* relations to prove that an action *happens-before* the other.

In your program, the `atomicInteger = 0;` write is guaranteed to be seen by the threads misleadingly named “reader” and “writer”, as you start them afterwards.

> - If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
>
> …
>
> - A call to `start()` on a thread *happens-before* any actions in the started thread.

The new threads invoke the `synchronized` method, which ensures that one thread executes the method after the other, so one thread will see the initial zero value and the other is guaranteed to see the result of the first update.

> - An unlock on a monitor *happens-before* every subsequent lock on that monitor.

To ensure that the thread executing the `test` method will see the `2` or in other words, that the update made by the second thread *happens-before* the `atomicInteger == 2` test, you could encapsulate the test in a `synchronized(this) { … }` block, using the relation cited above. Or you wait for the completion of the threads, e.g. calling `reader.join(); writer.join();` before the test.

> All actions in a thread *happen-before* any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

As said by others, declaring the `atomicInteger` variable as `volatile` would also solve the issue as

> - A write to a `volatile` field ([§8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field.

but you would still have to declare the `dd()` method `synchronized` as the `++` operator is not atomic.